# Place 2 input fields on the same row when the number of input fields is not known

Tags: html, css, angular

I am currently working on an angular application. I am using *ngFor to add input fields because the number of inputs is not always the same (it depends on the data received from backend). I there a way to make sure that 2 input fields are placed on the same row?

The html code looks like this

```
<div *ngFor="let content of group?.Content">
    <label>content.Title</label>
    <input type="text">     
</div>
```

Comment: you would have to control this with an index on the for, and whether remainder after division by 2 was 0 or 1. Then use an *ngIf to see if RHS on last row needed an input or some sort of placeholder like a span perhaps. Others may add their 2 cents. https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives `<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes; let i=index; let odd=odd; trackBy: trackById" [class.odd]="odd">  ({{i}}) {{hero.name}}
</div>`. You may  have to make sure input is inline rather than block with some CSS too. Not sure off top of my head,

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bootsrap of Flex to Make sure 2 inputs take a row .
Example:

```
<div *ngFor="let X of Xs">
 <input class='col-md-6' type="text" value='X'>     
</div>
```